# Android , getting array from server and use it to build list view

Tags: php, android

This is php array that i want to pass

```
$array = array("item1","item2","item3");

echo json_encode($array);
```

And I using this to get the array

```
String content = Converter.convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
String[] str= jsobOnject.getJSONArray();
```

I am trying to store the array to str, but I duno what parameter I should put at jsobOnject.getJSONArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you positive you are wanting a value from a method on the object jsobOnject ?

This appears to be a typo.

See revised code block

```
String content = Converter.convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);
String[] str = jsonObject.getJSONArray();
```

Also, if you want to store a String of the JSON Object, you would do the following

```
String str = jsonObject.toString();
```

Further reading:

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()

From Javadoc for JSONObject.toString():

> Encodes this object as a compact JSON string, such as:
>
> {"query":"Pizza","locations":[94043,90210]}